# Look for hierarchy standard for Java projects

Tags: java, maven, ant, build, hierarchy

I am searching for hierarchy standard for Java projects and only
found this link:

http://java.sun.com/blueprints/code/projectconventions.html

I think that Ant, Maven, Gradle like SE, ME, EE must have silimar
structure so it is not sufficient which project type you use...

Answer (score 3):

Use maven structure ([details](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html)):

```
my-app
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   `-- java
    |       `-- com
    |           `-- mycompany
    |               `-- app
    |                   `-- App.java
    `-- test
        `-- java
            `-- com
                `-- mycompany
                    `-- app
                        `-- AppTest.java
```

Comment: What rationale to use **main** in **src/main/java**?

Comment: To easily separate production code from your test classes, since you don't want to package those.

Comment: also allows for other jvm languages like groovy, scala etc. one would have main/groovy and main/scala

Comment: @flesk Oh, sorry. I badly look to example... Some project store **test** under same level as **src** dir.